# How to rewrite the url in yii2

Tags: php, yii, wamp, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have installed yii2 on my system. The default url is `localhost/projectname/backend/web/`.

I want my url should be `http://localhost/projectname` for frontend and `http://localhost/projectname/admin` for backend. I am following the 2nd answer i.e given by despotbg of this link [Yii2 htaccess - How to hide frontend/web and backend/web COMPLETELY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely) but I am getting the following error

> Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::request

please suggest me how can i remove this error so that i can rewrite my project url. I am working on wamp server

Comment: This most likely has nothing to do with yii but to do with your virtual host setup. I would ask this question on the wamp questions page.

Comment: I cleaned up your syntax some (wrapping your example URLs lets other people know it's not a link) but you might want to post some more code details so other readers can help you. I also tagged this as wamp per your question and the other comment.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was Updated And now work fine...

Frontend

Modify file frontend/config/main.php:

```
....
    'components' => [
        ....
        'request'=>[
            'baseUrl'=>'/projectname',
        ],
        'urlManager'=>[
            'scriptUrl'=>'/projectname/index.php',
        ],
        // use the following, if you want to enable speaking URL for the frontend
//        'urlManager' => [
//            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
//            'showScriptName' => false,
//        ],
    ],
```

Backend

Modify file backend/config/main.php:

```
....
    'components' => [
        ....
        'request'=>[
            'baseUrl'=>'/projectname/admin',
        ],
        'urlManager'=>[
            'scriptUrl'=>'/projectname/admin/index.php',
        ],
        // use the following, if you want to enable speaking URL for the backend
//        'urlManager' => [
//            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
//            'showScriptName' => false,
//        ],
    ],
```

Apache (.htaccess with mod_rewrite)

Create a file .htaccess in the project root directory (where composer.json is):

```
RewriteEngine On

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```

[source](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/799/yii2-app-advanced-on-single-domain-apache-nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

backend\config\main.php

```
// backend, under components array
         'request'=>[
             'class' => 'common\components\Request',
             'web'=> '/backend/web',
             'adminUrl' => '/admin'
         ],
         'urlManager' => [
                 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                 'showScriptName' => false,
         ],
```

create request.php file on common\components

```
<?php

namespace common\components;


class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
    public $web;
    public $adminUrl;

    public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
    }


    /*
        If you don't have this function, the admin site will 404 if you leave off 
        the trailing slash.

        E.g.:

        Wouldn't work:
        site.com/admin

        Would work:
        site.com/admin/

        Using this function, both will work.
    */
    public function resolvePathInfo(){
        if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
            return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Try this i hope this will help you..