# yii2: Windows Server (500 - Internal server error)

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, yii2, windows-server

I have developed an application using yii2 advanced template. I used [mohit's answer to hide fronted/web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely) and it successfully works in my localhost. In our office, we have a windows server. I know that I have to convert the `.htaccess` file to `web.config` in order for it to work in the windows server. I used this [online .htaccess to web.config converter](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx#result).

But the server had this reply.

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Here is the .htaccess given by @mohit.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with admin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kalahi/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kalahi/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kalahi/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kalahi/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kalahi/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

And here is the converted web.config

```
<rule name="rule 1V" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^admin/assets/(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/assets/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2V" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^admin/css/(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/css/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3V" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/index.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4V" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^assets/(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/frontend/web/assets/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 5V" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^css/(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/frontend/web/css/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

**WHERE DID I GO WRONG??? PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: You should look at your logs and see if you find more information.

Comment: what logs do you mean sir??

Comment: were you able to resolve it?