# Yii2 advanced theme backend access

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

i'm having a problem accessing the backend section of my advanced theme. Basically i can't access after make changes in .htaccess for frontend section. 
In root folder the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/web/(assets|css|stylesheets|images|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
    RewriteRule .* frontend/web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: You need to configure backend rules in .htaccess too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the pretty url component in either `frontend` / `backend` application of the yii2-advenced template, make sure you create a .`htaccess` file under the web folder of the respective application with the following content

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

NOTE: `rewrite_module` should be enabled in apache for this to work.