# Remove index.php from url after removing web folder from frontend and backend in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to remove `index.php` from url. I put `.htaccess` in the root and wrote the following lines in `common/config/main-local.php`.
But every url is redirected to backend.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

My `common/config/main-local.php` file:

```
'urlManager' => [
  'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
  // Disable index.php
  'showScriptName' => false,
  // Disable r= routes
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'rules' => array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
   ),
],
```

Note: I want to remove `index.php` from both frontend and backend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii2 htaccess - How to hide frontend/web and backend/web COMPLETELY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely)

Answer (score -1):

In .htaccess file(put .htaccess in frontend/web and backend/web )

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And in frontend/config/main.php and backend/config/main.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ],
    ],
```

Comment: But I have removed web folder.. where can I put these .htacess.

Comment: my frontend controller is working fine for view page.. But backend controller cannot find the view page.. always calling backend index page

Comment: Put it in root directory of project and edit backend and frontend config like the above code

Comment: Not working .. now every link in the menu is redirecting to sitename/backend/site/index..