# Yii2 Advance Application Remove '/web' and 'index.php' in frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I referred the below given link

[Yii2 htaccess - How to hide frontend/web and backend/web COMPLETELY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely)

[Remove index.php from url after removing web folder from frontend and backend in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645180/remove-index-php-from-url-after-removing-web-folder-from-frontend-and-backend-in)

but, i did't get the output

**show below URL**

localhost/yii2advance/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin

localhost/yii2advance/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin

in above url i remove `/web/index.php` in both `frontend` and `backend`

**I get URL like**

localhost/yii2advance/backend/site/login

localhost/yii2advance/frontend/site/login

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/

Comment: your refer link remove `frontend/web`. i remove the `/web/index.php` in both `frontend` and `backend`

Answer (score 7):

1- put this code in .htaccess flie in yii2advance folder (main folder of project)

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

above code convert

> 'localhost/yii2advance/frontend/web/index.php'

to

> 'localhost/yii2advance/'

and it convert

> 'localhost/yii2advance/backend/web/index.php'

to

> 'localhost/yii2advance/admin'

2- add this code to frontend/web/.htaccess and backend/web/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

3- in backend/config/main.php put this codes:

```
'homeUrl' => '/yii2advance/admin',
'components' => [
'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance/admin', // localhost/yii2advance/admin
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
         'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
         'showScriptName' => false,
         'rules' => [],
    ],
```

4- in frontend/config/main.php put this codes:

```
'homeUrl' => '/yii2advance',
'components' => [
'request' => [
    'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance', // localhost/yii2advance
 ],
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [],
],
```

Comment: Hay! man, that cool everything working fine. the only change is 'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '/yii2advance', // localhost/yii2advance
    ], it should come inside the components

Answer (score -1):

Create a ".htaccess" file in the "web" directory with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My [pull request](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/pull/206) was accepted about this. It will be in the 2.0.19 version.