# Yii2 pretty Url - assets not working

Tags: php, yii2, symlink, friendly-url, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using Yii2 advanced template. Where I want to hide 'backend/web/index.php' & 'frontend/web/index.php' too. I'm able to achieve this with following code -

***.htaccess at root -***

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule .* backend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

***.htaccess at frontend & backend's web -***

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

***frontend config -***

```
'request'=>[
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web'=> '/frontend/web'
        ],
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

***backend config -***

```
'request'=>[
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web'=> '/backend/web',
            'adminUrl' => '/admin'
        ],
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
```

BUT, the problem with this is it doesn't load any css (asset). The pages are displaying only text & html ***Like this -*** [image: pages without css]

I also tried to modify request component as -

```
'request'=>[
                'class' => 'common\components\Request',
                'web'=> '/frontend/web/assets'
            ],
```

then css works, But pretty url doesn't work. All the frontend/web/... or backend/web/... displayed then. 
[image: unwanted url part]
Please let me know where I'm going wrong. And tell me what should I do to keep URL pretty with proper assets.

Comment: Use VirtualHost for hiding your backend and frontend.. a lot more easier that way.

Comment: Doing that is easy btw.. Just follow the following tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Will it work anywhere? i.e. I've to run it regardless of environment, on windows, on linux, on hosting sites etc.

Comment: No.. settings for virtualhost would be different depending on server type.. What I gave you is for Apache2 on Ubuntu..

Comment: you will need to set it up manually. cpanel/webmin has interface to add addon domains btw..

Comment: Is there any another way that will just edit my existing code & get it worked?

Comment: Well try this thread out then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely .. This is untested btw. Not really sure about the side-effects.

Comment: @TusharWalzade have you register your css files in assets/AppAsset??

Comment: thanks for help, I'll try it

Comment: Not registered, please tell me your way

Comment: namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css =
    [
        'plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',

   

    ];

Comment: above code for  AppAsset.php in  assets foder

Comment: register it in your layout or in view as below

Comment: use app\assets\AppAsset;


AppAsset::register($this);

Comment: i have also faced this issue , there is a problem in registering your files

Comment: I've already registered assets in layouts/main.php