# Run Application from the desired location - yii2

Tags: php, yii2

This is my project structure

```
project1
    -assets
    -commands
    .
    .
    .
    modules
        -people
            -controllers
                -PeopleController.php
            -models
            -views
            People.php



    web
        -index.php
```

I'm deploying it to server. URL hit: https://11.11.11.11/project1/web/index.php/people/people/index

Where should I modify in server files, so that URL: https://11.11.11.11/people/people/index works for me? I don't want user to know the folder name where my codes are available.

Comment: You could use pretty urls: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls

Answer (score 1):

The answer varies depending on the type of server you use or the use of shared hosting
You can use this [tutorial](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md) to configure the server.

To remove web and index.php Or ... :
Add the following code to the config/web.php file:

```
 use \yii\web\Request;
 $baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

 $config = [
     #code...
     'components' => [
          // ...
         'request' => [
               // ...
              'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,  // Add baseUrl
         ],

         // ...
         'urlManager' => [
             'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,  // Add baseUrl
             'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
             'showScriptName' => false,
             'enableStrictParsing' => false,
             'rules' => [
                 // ...
             ],
         ],
         // ...
     ],
 ]
```

Tutorial on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely) can also help.